# ES6 import a file in multiple place, why the file loads once?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If there has a common file named `common.js`, and others such as `a.js`, `b.js`...

**common.js**

```
const Common = { property: 'initial' }
export { Common };
```

**a.js**

```
import { Common } from 'common.js';
Common.property = 'changed';
```

**b.js**

```
import { Common } from 'common.js';
console.log(Common.property);
```

First, `a.js` runs and load the `common.js` into memory.

Then, `b.js` run by engine.

1. Does the `common.js` will load again or use the existing `common.js` in the memory?
2. If `common.js` was updated by other `xx.js` script, how will the `import` behave?

Comment: 1.2 2. => 1. ... ;)

Comment: @torazaburo I thought this was a duplicate at first but it is not, just related. The linked question is about the code inside the module being executed. This question is about the an object returned from a module being mutated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Node.js so the `import` will turn into `require` statements after transpiling.

From the docs:

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to `require('foo')` will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

[Source](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching)

To answer you questions explicitly:

1. The module is cached so you are changing the same object
2. It will print the the last value assigned

   - for example `changed` if `a.js` was executed
   - if only `b.js` is executed, then it will print `initial`

Try it out online [here](https://glot.io/snippets/eskvuvzsch).

Comment: Thanks very much! I had understand. By the way, I using JavaScript(ES6) and compiled to ES5.

Answer (score 0):

Node != ES2015.

Specifically, and rather especially, the import system from ES2015 is different the require syntax from Node.

ES2015 does not allow you to change the shape of a module during runtime - the code is static while this is built up in memory.

As to what a practical implementation might do is up to question, but the TL;DR is that you should not change a file in between module loads or bad things may happen (TM)