# Polymer `<custom-style>`: which line of code stops appending to DOM multiple imports of the same custom-style template module?

Tags: javascript, polymer, vaadin, web-component, es6-modules

My project's upstream web components theme is implemented as `<custom-style>` elements [link](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/blob/master/color.html)

I want to implement my document level  overrides as a JS module (as in, avoid hardcoding into app `index.html` or equivalent), which on surface looks simple:

```js
import '@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/color.js';

const $template = document.createElement('template');

$template.innerHTML = `
<custom-style>
  <style>
  html,
  :host {
    --lumo-primary-color: red;
  }
  </style>
</custom-style>`;

document.head.appendChild($template.content);
```

**QUESTION**

Some web components used in the document also import original theme via `import '@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/color.js'`.

I want my overrides to always cascade last (without `!important` hacks).

Do multiple later `import '@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/color.js';` calls  have any potential to revert my CSS custom property overrides cascade?

Think:

- original: `--lumo-primary-color: hsl(214, 90%, 52%);`
- me: import original, override `--lumo-primary-color: red;`
- later: can a later import of original "reset" cascade back to `--lumo-primary-color: hsl(214, 90%, 52%);`)?

[ES6 import a file in multiple place, why the file loads once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638740/es6-import-a-file-in-multiple-place-why-the-file-loads-once) seems to imply maybe not, but I'm struggling finding any documentation that explicitly states something one way or another about `<custom-style>`.

Perhaps https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/v3.2.0/lib/elements/custom-style.js#L80 is the key?

**GLITCH**

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/roan-pizza?path=src/index.js seems to confirm repeated imports don't seem to cause a problem, but why? Is it purely due to ES6 module load caching, or is there something else to it?

EDIT drag-n-dropping `<custom-style>` elements around in browser inspector definitely has an effect on the cascade (colors change based on tag order), so at least loading order is confirmed to matter.

Comment: AFAIK imports are only parsed/executed once, so you’re correct in assuming that there’s no problem from later imports of color.js

Answer (score 0):

Tips: remove all for edit.

1. difference tags (of `<custom-style>`) by `#id` => `<custom-style id="id01">`.
2. save `<custom-style>` to edit => `save(#id)`.
3. red  (in "`--lumo-primary-color`") is a variable => `var color = red`.
4. remove all content of a `<custom-style id="id01">` => `remove_all(#id)`.
5. add a new content you need => as you did above.

I just hope that you will solve your problem. You are better than me so I will not write code.